# Delete Linux Partition From Windows

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot

My problem is that I am currently dual booting Kali Linux and Windows (Windows 7). I use GRUB to do this. How can I delete Kali Linux and GRUB without screwing up booting my computer? I want the deleted Kali Partion to be labeled as free space in Windows. Any help is appreciated. I would prefer to do this without 3rd party software.

Comment: You can use either the disk management snap-in or the diskpart cmd line utility to remove / resize, and the bcdboot cmd line utility to fix the bootloader. How you would do this exactly is going to depend on your partitioning scheme. If you need further help I'd suggest editing your post to include either a screenshot of disk management, or the output of `list partition` within diskpart with the proper drive selected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming computer has one MBR style disk:

Just rewrite MBR to Windows 7 format using bootsect.exe or any other tool which can do this.

```
bootsect /nt60 A: /MBR
```

bootsect.exe is available on in Windows recovery. A: is drive letter of active partition.

Rewriting MBR will remove Linux GRUB from there and later you can simply delete Linux partition.