# Remove Linux partition from Windows 11 Disk Management

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning

I resized my primary Windows 11 partition and created a small one to test a Linux distro but now I would like to remove it and if possible merge it back with the primary Windows 11 partition.

390GB (windows 11)
84.35GB (Linux)

But I am not sure about the other smaller partitions, which one is for windows and which is for linux and is it safe to just delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small partitions are recovery partitions and the UEFI partition. Do NOT delete these - no need and in the case of the EFI partition, you NEED this one.

So then if you are confident in deleting the Linux partition, you can delete that and then merge them with the disk partition tools readily available. Use very great care.

AOEMI and EaseUS are two such tools

Going forward, it is vastly easier and safer to use Virtual Machines. I do this and it very easy to manage.

Also remember to back up important data, email and documents before proceeding

Answer (score 0):

I think best practice is:

1. Boot from Linux live iso.
2. Using Gparted to format Linux partition , it seems like ext3,ext4, btrfs,
3. Don't' touch EFI Partition.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer) article is the most helpful one I found for dealing with this from windows. For compelteness [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1212103/delete-linux-partition-from-windows) is another related question that deals with this from Linux.

One thing not covered in either of these is the recovery partition. This is most likely a partition created by your computer vendor to help with recovery from windows errors - so dont delete it.

However it is difficult to tell this because the windows 11 disk manager does not show a file system type for this, which would suggest that windows does not recognize this partition, which should mean that this is a linux recovery partition. You can however confirm the file system type via the following steps (which in my case showed the partition to be a windows recovery partition):

1. In the command prompt, type in `diskpart`. This will require you grant admin permissions to open a new command prompt.
2. In the new window type `list vol`. This will show all the volumes. If the volume is a windows volume it will show up as NTFS under fs.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyOBF2ePvHY) video shows more about the above commands. However note that it mistakenly suggests deleting EFI.